# How to draw dashed border style in react native

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I am using below style, I am trying to draw dashed border style but it always coming solid . Please suggest .

```
<View style={{paddingLeft:10,
 height:300, marginBottom:10, 
 borderWidth:1,
 borderStyle: 'dashed',
 borderColor:'red',
 borderTopColor:'white'}}>
```

// Thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to add `borderRadius: 1` to make it work.

Comment: in this style just i have to add borderRadius: 1 ? rit

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17251 Check this, and yes

Comment: thanks .one question , If I have to remove top border then? how can I remove it?

Comment: Abhigyan try this

borderBottomLeftRadius: number
borderBottomRightRadius: number
borderTopLeftRadius: number
borderTopRightRadius: number

Also you will read this artical this give you more info on style ----  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet

Comment: NOTE: As of writing, applying `borderStyle` to a single border edge is broken in React Native 0.63.2 but there is an open PR to fix this limitation: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/29099

Comment: remove borderTopColor and add some borderRadius!

Answer (score 7):

According to github issue comments
(https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24224):

```
<View style={[{ height: 1, overflow: 'hidden' }]}>
  <View style={[{ height: 2, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#ddd', borderStyle: 'dashed' }]}></View>
</View>
```

Comment: nice ... but you also need a `borderRadius` for it to work in android. Can be super low though like `borderRadius: 0.01`

Comment: This is (sadly) the right way to avoid issues with top and bottom borders offsetting and creating a strange zigzag pattern... Thanks for posting

Comment: Thanks for that!! Worked like a charm

Answer (score 6):

Try following it should work

```
borderStyle: 'dotted',
borderRadius: 1,
```

Comment: thanks .one question , If I have to remove top border then? how can I remove it?

Comment: NOTE: As of writing, applying `borderStyle` to a single border edge is broken in React Native 0.63.2 but there is an open PR to fix this limitation: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/29099

Answer (score 4):

Try this  works fine for me;-)

```
<View style={{ height: '100%',
               borderRadius : 1,
               width: '100%',
               borderStyle: 'dashed',
               borderWidth: 1,
               borderColor: 'rgba(161,155,183,1)'}} />
```

Comment: Thanks, but why it doesn't work without specifying a borderRadius

Answer (score 3):

Following will work perfectly:

```
<View style={{
  paddingLeft:10,
  height:300,
  marginBottom:10,
  borderStyle: 'dashed',
  borderRadius: 1,
  borderWidth: 1,
  borderColor: 'red',
  borderTopColor:'white'
 }} />
```

Comment: remove borderTopColor, otherwise unsupported dashed / dotted border style warning

Answer (score 1):

It's worth adding that borderRadius needs to be applied to all sides globally using `borderRadius` rather than applying it to individual sides, as this seems to break styled borders on Android.

In my case I was using a Tailwind utility style `rounded-2xl`:

```
    "rounded-2xl": {
        "borderTopLeftRadius": 16,
        "borderTopRightRadius": 16,
        "borderBottomRightRadius": 16,
        "borderBottomLeftRadius": 16
    }
```

Exchanging this for `borderRadius: 16` solved the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks for this! Also using nativeWind

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to your code

```
<View style={{borderWidth:1, borderStyle="dashed", width:100, height:100}}></Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove borderTopColor

```
<View style={{paddingLeft:10,
 height:300, marginBottom:10, 
 borderWidth:1,
 borderStyle: 'dashed',
 borderColor:'red'}}>
```